# getBoundingClientRect() doesn't return height and width of SVG rect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I need a pair of fresh eyes to show me what I am doing wrong.

I want to get `height` and `width` and use them to work out the position of another element.

**HTML**

```
<g>
    <rect
        class="graphic"
        draggable="data"
        ng-attr-x="{{ data.x }}"
        ng-attr-y="{{ data.y }}"
        ng-attr-height="{{ data.height }}"
        ng-attr-width="{{ data.width }}"
    ></rect>
</g>
```

**Function for returning values I want**

```
function getSVGRectDimensions(element) {
    //logging
    console.log('firstChild', element[0].firstElementChild);
    console.log('firstChild.Clientrect', element[0].firstElementChild.getBoundingClientRect());

    var viewportOffset = element[0].firstElementChild.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (!element.jquery) {
            element = angular.element(element);
        }
        return {
            left: viewportOffset.left,
            height: viewportOffset.height,
            top: viewportOffset.top,
            width: viewportOffset.width
        }
    }
```

**How I use the function**

```
var svgElement = getSVGRectDimensions(data.element);
```

**In the console I get**

[image]

From the logs, you can see that `height` and `width` of `rect` > 0.

```
<rect class="graphic" draggable="data" ng-attr-x="{{ data.x }}" ng-attr-y="{{ data.y }}" ng-attr-height="{{ data.height }}" ng-attr-width="{{ data.width }}" x="1033.78" y="364" height="46.22000000000003" width="106.8900000000001"></rect>
```

And yet, when I call the function with `getBoundingClientRect()`, `height` and `width` = 0.

```
firstChild.Clientrect ClientRect {} bottom: 60.999996185302734 height: 0 left: 681.1538696289062 right: 681.1538696289062 top: 60.999996185302734 width: 0 __proto__: ClientRect
```

Why is that happening?

I also tried to get rid of `firstElementChild`, which results in returning `g` instead of `rect` but still `height` and `width` = 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect getBoundingClientRect returns four values: top, left, bottom, right. 
In your console you can see that these four values are present. Calculating the width and height from these values is trivial

you use:

```
var viewportOffset = element[0].firstElementChild.getBoundingClientRect();
```

which returns a DOMRect and then later:

```
return {
        left: viewportOffset.left,
        height: viewportOffset.height,
        top: viewportOffset.top,
        width: viewportOffset.width
    }
```

as I said, viewportOffset is a DOMRect which **does not have** properties **width and height**. **Instead** they have **right, bottom**.

so to work out your width and height, your return code should look like this:

```
return {
        left: viewportOffset.left,
        height: viewportOffset.bottom - viewportOffset.top,
        top: viewportOffset.top,
        width: viewportOffset.right - viewportOffset.left
    }
```

Comment: But `viewportOffset.bottom` - `viewportOffset.top` would give `height` as 0 still.